# Memory Leak on setting node to new Node()

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I've created a binary search tree that I thought was working totally fine, until I started trying to use it for a set implementation. I'm running into a problem with some memory leaks that appear to happen on adding nodes to the tree. I've extrapolated my `addNode` function to really see where the problem was happening and this is the line Valgrind is pointing to.

```
bool addNode(const T &data) override {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new Node(); // <--- THIS LINE IS SHOWING UP
        root->left = nullptr;
        root->right = nullptr;
        root->data = data;
        return true;
    }
    return addNode(root, data);
}
```

When I run it with Valgrind, this is the output I get.

[image: Valgrind Memory Leak]

I have 2 questions.

**QUESTION 1:** Is this error actually pointing at the line where the memory leak starts? Or is it the place where the memory leak shows up?

**QUESTION 2:** How would I get this not to happen? I'm happy to post any code that you feel you need to answer this question, but I'm not exactly sure where to start. Hopefully this can start someone in the right direction.

**EDIT:** I should mention that this is a school project, hence any "weird" things like bool functions where you don't need it and other things. Please ask before assuming I'm doing something that doesn't need to be done.

**EDIT 2:** Here is some code:

```
BST() {
    root = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}
```

And some more:

```
class Set: SetInterface<T> {
private:
    BST<T> tree;
public:
    bool insert(const T &item) override {
        return tree.addNode(item);
    }
...
}
```

The Set is the value in a HashMap implementation that takes a string as the key.

Here is my destructor:

```
~BST() override {
    this->clearTree();
}
```

and `clearTree()`:

```
private:
void clearTree(Node*& node) {
    if (node == nullptr) return;
    // Delete the children, then delete the given node
    clearTree(node->left);
    clearTree(node->right);
    delete node;
    node = nullptr;
}
public:
bool clearTree() override {
    clearTree(root);
    size = 0;
    return true;
}
```

As just a little more, although I don't know how understandable it is, this is how I'm using it, when it gives an error. When I just do a set of strings, I don't get any memory leaks. When I do the set of strings inside of a HashMap, it does come up. Here's the code where I'm using it.

```
HashMap<string, Set<string>> ineffectives;
while (getline(in, line)) {
    stringstream ss(line);
    // ... A bunch of if statements ...
    string move, otherMove;
    ss >> move;
    ineffectives[move] = Set<string>();
    while (ss >> otherMove) {
        ineffectives[move].insert(otherMove);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't (never) use raw pointers and manual memory management in c++. YAGNI appiles for 98% of any use cases.

Comment: Can you please explain? What do you mean by that? And what does YAGNI mean?

Comment: WIthout your code, this is nearly impossible to answer.  Here's a possibility; did `root` have a value before you said `root = new Node();`.  If it did, you are leaking whatever `root` used to point to.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer _"And what does YAGNI mean?"_ It's a well known acronym for _You ain't gonna need it_. As for more explanations take a look at the standard c++ [container classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: I'm finding some more code to add.

Comment: That just shows where the object that's eventually leaked was allocated.  Do you assign to `root` anywhere else?  Do you ever `delete root`?

Comment: @EthanBrouwer As for your mini mini example: `root = new Node();` How do you care about the previously allocated value of `root` before just overriding that? Give us a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. With the code I've added above, can you lead me in the right direction at least? Should I be looking at my tree class? Or should I be looking where I'm using it in the HashMap class?

Comment: @EthanBrouwer No, I am insisting for a [mcve] as already mentioned.

Comment: 1: This is impossible to diagnose with just scraps. You need to post a Minimal Compilable Example that has the issue. 2: Not knowing anything about the code. But because it has RAW pointers I am betting you are violating the rule of three or some other issue like that.

Comment: I think the bug is somewhere else in your code. Yes the leak may have been allocated here but somewhere else you are either forgetting to call delete and/or you are replacing `root` with some new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem. The following line is in the last piece of code I posted:

```
ineffectives[move] = Set<string>();
```

It's uneccesary and causes the leak because when I declare

```
HashMap<string, Set<string>>
```

It already creates all the string sets. When I remove that line, it works without a leak.